# How to update Checkboxes state from cell values

Tags: vb.net, excel, checkbox

I have been searching but I couldn't find anything about this: I am coding a basic VBA Form for the office making easier some procedures, as this file is shared but only opened by one person at a time, I am trying to make my form load all of the data stored on a certain Excel file. I have been able to do everything EXCEPT reading the values in an active sheet from Cell `B2:B13` to update the Checkboxes (Tristate) States.... Any help with this? I have some Textboxes that work (almost the same) as the checkboxes and could figure them out... But checkboxes need the checkstate to change the status...

Specific question: How can I update `ICheckBox1`, through `ICheckbox12`, depending on the values of the cells `B2:B13`, within the active worksheet depending of the selected index in ComboBox.... I have this for my Textboxes and works perfectly:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged 
  oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(ComboBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex + 1) 

  For i As Integer = 2 To 13
       Me.TabPage1.Controls("ITextBox" & (i - 1)).Text = oXLSheet.Cells(i, 1).value'("ICheckBox" & (i - 1)).CheckState = oXLSheet.Cells(i, 2).value 
  Next      
End Sub
```

The commented part is the one I am trying to figure out... Thanks!

Comment: `1` If only one user is opening the file at any given point of time then I would recommend not to keep your file as shared :). Shared files tend to get corrupt very fast. `2` Regarding the checkboxes, what values do the range `B2:B13` hold?

Comment: Also it seems like you are doing this in VB.Net?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to only share it by sending the file. B2:B13 store values "0,1,2" Depending on the checkstate it should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are trying to use is correct.
You just need to store 0, 1, 2 in your spreadsheet column, as the case may be.
Use the following substitutions:

- Unchecked = 0
- Checked   = 1
- Indeterminate  = 2

-

```
Private Sub ComboBoxCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxCustomers.SelectedIndexChanged
    oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(ComboBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex + 1)

    For i As Integer = 2 To 13
        CType(Me.TabPage1.Controls("ICheckBox" & (i - 1)), System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).CheckState = oXLSheet.Cells(i, 2).value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If I write 

`Me.TabPage1.Controls("ICheckBox" & (i - 1)).CheckState`

there is an error message telling that Checkstate is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Control...

Comment: You need to typecast it to CheckBox to let the compiler know its type. I just updated my code above.

Comment: Tested it with the code modification provided, and now this error appears: 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred.

`Object'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.CheckBox'.`

Is this because the Controls are inside a TabControler? Or because they were added from Controls Toolbox?

Comment: OK.. I didn't know what type your CheckBox is. So in that case, just try typecasting it to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.CheckBox` instead of `CheckBox`. Updated my code above again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I lost internet connection... Weird, I try with the code provided but the code error is the same. `Object'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.CheckBox'.`

Comment: It could be because of ambiguity of namespaces. Try using the full namespace `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`. Updated my code above again.